# MySQL split and join the values

Tags: mysql

I have a table [mapping] with 2 columns similar to below

```
id  | values
1   | 1,2
2   | 1,2,3
3   | 1,1
4   | 1,1,2
```

and another table [map] is similar to this

```
sno | values
1   | Test
2   | Hello
3   | Hai
```

My expected output is

```
id  | values
1   | Test,Hello
2   | Test,Hello,Hai
3   | Test,Test
4   | Test,Test,Hello
```

Is it possible? If it is please can anybody build a query for me.

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because I don't even know whether is it possible or not and for the reason I have mention in the end of the post "Is it possible? @jedifans"

Comment: Can you change the scheme? Because right now with this scheme you have really bad data consistency. Table `mapping` should have columns: `map_id` and `value_id`, and then you can keep in database multiple rows with one map_id.

Comment: You are telling me to change the column names or else anything other? @MarekSkiba

Comment: you should have the first table to hold a record for each row, not more than one. So for id=1 you will have: (id=1, value=1) and (id=1, value=2). This way you will be able to do a join between the two tables. This is the right way to do this kind of tasks

Comment: @SathvikCheela: I update my comment, it's not only about change the column name. Check also the @LelioFaieta he sad this same. If you change the scheme you can even add the relations between column, so if you delete some record from `map` table  it will be removed automatically from `mapping` table - this is about data consistency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) to join the tables and [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to concat the values :

```
SELECT s.sno,GROUP_CONCAT(s.values) as `values` 
FROM mapping t
INNER JOIN map s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.id,t.values))
GROUP BY s.sno
```

**Note:** You should know that this is a very bad DB structure. This may lead to a lot more complicated queries and will force you to over complicate things. You should [Normalize](http://www.computerweekly.com/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps) your data, split it , and place each `ID` in a separate record!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will put that in mind. But for my original data, I cannot put the way you suggested and whatever I am post is completely different with my DB schema.@sagi

Comment: this should be:
```SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.values)
FROM mapping t
INNER JOIN map s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.id,t.values))
GROUP BY t.id```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    `ids`.`id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`values`.`texts`) AS texts
FROM
    `ids`
INNER JOIN `values` ON FIND_IN_SET(`values`.`id`, `ids`.`values`)
GROUP BY
    `ids`.`id`
```

It works like this: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d72e5/1)