# How to select data from one column has multiple values using join from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two table . **traveller** and **city**

city table :

```
City_id     City_name
  1           Delhi
  2           Mumbai
  3           Newyork
  4           Sydney
```

User table :

```
 traveller_name traveled_city
    harry             1,2
    peter             2,3,4
    john             2,4
```

How to fetch city traveled by traveller like this ?

```
  traveller_name       travelled_city
    harry               Delhi , Mumbai
```

Comment: Is the value of city in user table comma separated? OR there will be multiple records for different travelled cities by a user?

Comment: your data appears to be de-normalised. if you find yourself storing more than one item in a single field like you do in traveled_city then it's time for a re-design. You need a child table with a foreign key back to the user table. Maybe you need to study relational database design further before you continue with your project.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139393/mysql-split-and-join-the-values

Comment: I'm with ADyson here. This is a bad datamodel. You are not really using the relational database system, as you are supposed to do. Change your structure to `city(city_id, city_name)`, `user(user_id, user_name)`, `city_user(city_id, user_id)`.

Comment: @strawberry please give me link

Comment: @Marriage look at the yellow box at the top of the page...the link is there already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema is not normalized. The [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) tells that you need to have atomic values in the field. Also considering other normal forms, you need to have separate `User` table and `UserCity` table.

If you normalize your table, then your queries will become simpler.

**User Table**

```
--------+----------
| UserId UserName  |
--------+----------
|   1   | Harry   |
|   2   | Peter   |
-------------------
```

**UserCity Table**  (It is Bridge table)

```
--------+----------
| UserId CityId |
--------+----------
|   1   | 1     |
|   1   | 2     |
-------------------
```

Now, you can easily query

```
SELECT u.UserName as traveller_name, group_concat(c.cityname,',') as  travelled_city
FROM User as u
JOIN UserCity as uc
ON u.UserId = uc.UserId
JOIN City as c
ON uc.CityId = c.CityId
GROUP BY u.UserName
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT traveller.traveller_name, GROUP_CONCAT(city.City_name)
FROM traveller
INNER JOIN city ON city.City_id = traveller.traveled_city_id
GROUP BY traveller.traveller_name

Comment: `city.City_id = traveller.traveled_city` will never be true because traveled_city contains multiple IDs...OP's data is de-normalised. The DB design needs fixing before there is a neat solution to this.

Comment: @ADyson yes.it giving only one city name

Comment: that's why we used group_concat  which gives comma separated strings